# Getting exception in System.Net.HttpClient - A redirect request will change a secure to a non-secure connection

Tags: windows-10

I am developing a Universal windows 10 app in which I need to integrate some payment gateways. I am getting an exception while interacting with the payment gateway. Exception is as follows:

> The text associated with this error code could not be found. A redirect request will change a secure to a non-secure connection.

Surprisingly my Win 8.1 Desktop app (with same code) is working absolutely fine and I am able to communicate with the payment gateway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between Desktop Apps and Universal Apps must be a side-effect of recent [.NET Native changes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/07/28/net-networking-apis-for-uwp-apps.aspx) ([read more](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/08/20/net-native-what-it-means-for-universal-windows-platform-uwp-developers/)).

The error (*0x80072f08*) means you are doing a **HTTPS** request that is responding with a redirection to a **HTTP** url.

You will need to turn off auto-redirections and do the redirection yourself.

Try:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect ||
    response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently)
{
    Uri redirectUri = response.Headers.Location;

    // TODO: Repeat request with redirectUri ...
}
```